# Angular hybrid app : how to unit test my bootstrap module?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, hybrid

I've got a hybrid AngularJs/Angular app. The app's bootstrap is done within the Angular app in my AppModule with ngDoBootstrap(); like so :

```
ngDoBootstrap() {
        this.upgrade.bootstrap(document.body, ['my.angularjs.app']);
}
```

I would like to unit-test this, to make sure that the bootstrap is done. 
But I can't seem to find the proper documentation to unit-test modules in the official documentation (https://angular.io/guide/testing)

PS : the code above is just a small example. I do a bunch of things in the constructor as well that I would like to test.

Anyone has already done this? thx for your help

---

EDIT : 
here is my test so far :

```
import { TestBed, inject } from '@angular/core/testing';
import {AppModule} from "./app.module";

describe('AppModule', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [AppModule]
        });
    });

    it('should call ngDoBootstrap', () => {
        spyOn(AppModule, 'ngDoBootstrap');
        AppModule.ngDoBootstrap();
        expect(AppModule.AppModule).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

When I run the tests i've got this errors

```
error TS2345: Argument of type '"ngDoBootstrap"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"prototype"'.
error TS2339: Property 'ngDoBootstrap' does not exist on type 'typeof AppModule'.
error TS2339: Property 'AppModule' does not exist on type 'typeof AppModule'.
```

Answer (score 0):

In your test suite did you try something like this :

```
spyOn(upgrade, 'bootstrap')
component.ngDoBootstrap()
expect(component.upgrade.bootstrap).toHaveBeenCalled()
```

`upgrade` is a service I assume right ?

Comment: yes `upgrade` is a service. but in my case I dont have a component but a module. and I can't find a way to instantiate my module. I'll update my question with more code.

Comment: i don't think there is something for what you want. haven't seen anything like that.